# Dark tile layers without country/province borders (for Leaflet?)

Tags: maps, leaflet, visualization

I am looking for dark/black tile layers without country/province borders for a leaflet project. I have used [Carto DB's DarkMatterNoLabels](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/), but this is not optimal.

Does anyone know suitable tile layers?
Alternatively, can I get tile layers elsewhere and feed them into leaflet?

Have a good weekend,
Naibaf

Comment: What exactly is wrong with DarkMatterNoLabels for your use case?

Comment: Two reasons: 1. Mapping 1950-2015 data, boundaries changed and those changes would go unnoticed. 2. Some boundaries are contended (e.g. Kashmir).

Comment: Ah, for historical content it makes sense. Much of the other content, even coastlines and inland water bodies changed quite a bit since 1950...

Comment: Good point reg coastlines and inland water bodies. I'm drawing power stations, so this should be fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the amount of zoom levels and the extend you need, you could also generate some tiles using QGIS and use that as a tile source.

Maybe you can use [Hydda.Base](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=Hydda.Base) with a css filter to change it's appearance? [leaflet-tilefilter](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-tilefilter) might be a good start.

Actually, you can also just use the principle leaflet-tilefilter uses under the hood, which is:

```
.leaflet-tile {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg) invert(100%);
}
```

This actually looks quite nice: [demo](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/zoxe/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

I'd give https://www.mapbox.com/ a try, or else download OpenStreetMap data and render your own tiles, using tools such as https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik.